# Macro Row and Column copying

Tags: vba, excel

Struggling to get my head round this Macro and why it won't work.

I've picked up off someone else and every time I try and edit it, it comes back to De-Bug.

The aim is for it to Copy the rows above in the table on sheet 1, Row C into the next row - but I want it to copy information from above for column I:J and K:L.

Also, when the columns are copied and inserted in on "Advisor Week", the code has been made with columns which I want to have Hidden, so when ran when the columns are hidden, it doesn't work correctly.

```
Dim Lr As Integer
Dim AWFr As Long, AWLc As Long

AWFr = 14

Lr = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Rows(Lr + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Cells(Lr + 1, "C") = Cells(Lr, "C") + 1
Rows(Lr).Copy
Rows(Lr + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

With Worksheets("Advisor Week")

    AWLc = .Cells(AWFr, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Cells(AWFr, AWLc - 5).Resize(, 5).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
    .Columns(AWLc - 5).ColumnWidth = 0.5
    .Columns(AWLc - 9).Resize(, 5).Copy Destination:=.Columns(AWLc - 4)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With
```

I can happily send images if needed but don't have enough Rep to post on here

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of this code and I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Which line are you getting an error on?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer.  I would have asked my questions in comments except that I have documented your macro and wanted to share the result.  I should perhaps have updated your questions with the revised macro but have decided it is better to keep it separate.

Before attempting to amend inherited code, I make sure I know exactly what it does.  If necessary, I will step through statement by statement and document each statement.  Like D_Zab, I do not understand what this code is attempting.  Is this the original code or the partially amended?

You say “column I:J and K:L” and not “columns I:L”?  What is significance of this?

In my experiments, the presence of hidden columns does not make a difference.

I am sorry but I do not know what this means: “The aim is for it to Copy the rows above in the table on sheet 1, Row C into the next row - but I want it to copy information from above for column I:J and K:L.”

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

  Dim Lr As Integer
  Dim AWFr As Long, AWLc As Long

  AWFr = 14

  ' Find last used row in column C of active worksheet
  Lr = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  ' Insert row below last row in column C of active worksheet. If other
  ' columns have values below the last used row in C, those values will
  ' be moved down one row. The formatting (except borders) of the last
  ' used row in C is copied to the inserted row.
  Rows(Lr + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

  ' Add 1 to last cell in column C of active worksheet and store in
  ' next row down.
  Cells(Lr + 1, "C") = Cells(Lr, "C") + 1

  ' Copy formats (including borders) from last row with a value
  ' in column C of active worksheet to next row down.
  Rows(Lr).Copy
  Rows(Lr + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

  With Worksheets("Advisor Week")

    ' Find last used column in row 14
    AWLc = .Cells(AWFr, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Insert columns to move last used column in row 14, and the four
    ' columns to its left, to the right
    .Cells(AWFr, AWLc - 5).Resize(, 5).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToLeft

    ' Set column width of first new column to half the width of character "0"
    ' which is 7 pixels with Tahoma 10.5.
    .Columns(AWLc - 5).ColumnWidth = 0.5

    ' Copy the four columns to the left of the inserted columns, and the
    ' first inserted (narrow) column, over the last four inserted columns
    ' and the first column that was shifted right
    .Columns(AWLc - 9).Resize(, 5).Copy Destination:=.Columns(AWLc - 4)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

  End With

End Sub
```